# What are some Servlet Container for Netty

Tags: java, servlets, netty, event-driven-design, servlet-container

I wanted to build myself a Web based chat application (something like hipchat or facebook chat)I think netty is the way for this since it is event driven, However. Netty does not have any servlet container. So How do I build my own servlet container for netty? or better yet how do you build your own ServletContainer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Netty is too low level for what you are trying to accomplish. If you want an embedded solution in which servlets can be executed, why not trying Jetty instead?

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

Comment: Is Jetty NIO/Event Driven?

Comment: It can be, and so can Tomcat. I suspect your concern is that you'll have many persistent connections open and thread per connection won't scale. You deal with this using either Netty or a servlet container that supports servlet 3.0 asynchronous API (pretty much all do). Which one you choose will depend on the programming model / API you're most comfortable with.